# Authlogic_Oauth calling GET /user_sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, linkedin-api, authlogic-oauth

I'm writing a rails 3 app and I'm trying to let people sign_in or sign_up using LinkedIn. I've followed the tutorial at https://github.com/datawrangling/linkedin_on_rails but I'm getting some weird results. For some reason, the application is calling a GET on /user_sessions after the POST /user_sessions which sends my credentials to LinkedIn. This is the log from rails server:

```
Started POST "/user_sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-16 21:56:13 -0700
Processing by UserSessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"M+W0ExS4FZE5wg/hPI6FzL4dnAGdTS/yllQWqOoSNRs=", 
"user_session"=>{"username"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"},
"login_with_oauth"=>"Login with LinkedIn"}
Redirected to https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=76e56c85-3896-419a-ab94-15a05332d04b
Completed 302 Found in 455ms


Started GET "/user_sessions?oauth_token=76e56c85-3896-419a-ab94-15a05332d04b&oauth_verifier=86765" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-16 21:56:13 -0700
Processing by UserSessionsController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"oauth_token"=>"76e56c85-3896-419a-ab94-15a05332d04b", "oauth_verifier"=>"86765"}
Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (1.9ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (78.3ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (3.3ms)
Rendered user_sessions/index.html.erb within layouts/application (94.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 103ms (Views: 101.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I've stubbed out :index for the user_sessions controller so that I don't fail with the error:

```
No route matches "/user_sessions"
```

but I don't understand why I'm not being redirected to the linked in login page and then back to my app. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you already logged in to linked in? And did you authorize your application already? If so, thats why you don't see the linked in login screen

Comment: Yes! You are exactly right. I was already logged in to LinkedIn. I logged out and now I see the redirect to log in to LinkedIn and when it comes back to my site the application is trying to use the index function in the /user_sessions controller. Thanks!

Comment: Ill post that as an answer so we can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you already logged in to LinkedIn? And did you authorize your application already?

If so, thats why you don't see the LinkedIn login screen.